# In AWS FreeRTOS, Problem with "Exception thrown: read access violation. pNetworkInfo->pNetworkInterface was 0x1"

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, freertos

I'm trying to send data from `AWS FreeRTOS` windows simulator to local `MQTT` broker. But every time I am getting this error:

> "Exception thrown: read access violation. pNetworkInfo->pNetworkInterface was 0x1".

Do you have any solution for this?